# How to change endpoint address in SOAP requests with ZEEP

Tags: python-3.x, soap, zeep

I am using ZEEP to make SOAP requests and it is easy and works great.

The problem is that the endpoint URL (in the WSDL) isn't correct.

I can solve the problem by editing the WSDL directly, but this isn't scalable.

I reviewed the ZEEP documentation about creating service proxies but I don't understand it and am having errors. Here is the part of the WSDL containing the bad URL:

```
</binding>
<service name="DeviceConfigurationService">
    <port name="DeviceConfigurationPort" 
binding="xrx:DeviceConfigurationBinding">
        <soap:address 
location="http://localhost/webservices/office/device_configuration/1"/>
    </port>
    </service>
```

the location is what I need to change. I need to change from "localhost" to a LAN IP address. This value may change frequently so I don't want to have to edit the WSDL every time.

Does anyone know how to do this with Zeep?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but I just had this same issue as I was accessing a third-party SOAP API with a WSDL that pointed to the wrong endpoint (the third party told me the correct endpoint but hadn't updated their WSDL). The accepted answer did point me in the right direction, but I'd like to offer some additional details that weren't immediately apparent to a fairly novice developer such as myself.

Start by noticing that [Zeep's documentation](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=create_service#zeep.Client.create_service) shows that the method zeep.Client.create_service() has two parameters.

> binding_name – The [QName](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QName) of the binding
>
> address – The address of the endpoint

**Figuring out the `binding_name`**

*Option 1 - Read through the WSDL*

The `binding_name` comes from the attribute `binding` in the WSDL. The issue is that the value of that attribute usually includes a reference to a name elsewhere in the WSDL that you have to manually resolve before using it to create a custom service.

In the case of the excerpt from the OP's WSDL, the value of `binding` is `"xrx:DeviceConfigurationBinding"`.

```
<service name="DeviceConfigurationService">
    <port name="DeviceConfigurationPort" binding="xrx:DeviceConfigurationBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost/webservices/office/device_configuration/1"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

While this is the `binding_name` used by Zeep, you can't just copy and paste it into the parameter of `create_service()` because it is partially comprised of `xrx` - a name defined locally within the WSDL. Zeep automatically resolves the value of this kind of name when it originally parses the WSDL, so when you tell Zeep to point an existing binding to a different endpoint you have to resolve the binding name yourself so Zeep knows which binding you are talking about (that's why @jeffgabhart used `{https://path-to-xrx-namespace}` in his answer). In the end you should end up with complete `binding_name` of the format `{NAMESPACE}BINDING`.

Note that `xrx` isn't the only possible name. For me, the name was `tns` and for you it may be something different. Whatever it is, you should be able to find the definition of that name somewhere in the WSDL.

*Option 2 - Use Zeep's WSDL parsing utility*

Another option is the one suggested by @576i. Running the command `python -mzeep WSDL_URL` will spit out the information Zeep gathers from the given WSDL. One heading should say "Bindings" followed by a list (possibly of length 1) of `binding_name`'s. From there you can copy the one you need to change the endpoint for.

*Option 3 - Get it from the Zeep Client object*

This one feels more like a hack, but `list(zeep_client.wsdl.port_types)` gives a list of all binding names that Zeep found in the WSDL used to create the `zeep_client`.

**Figuring out the `address`**

Lastly, for the sake of completeness, the `address` is simply the new endpoint you want to use instead of the one defined in the WSDL.

I hope this helps smooth out the learning curve for someone!

Answer (score 0):

```
client = Client('http://localhost/webservices/office/device_configuration/1?wsdl')

service = client.create_service(
    '{http://path-to-xrx-namespace}DeviceConfigurationBinding',
    'http://127.0.0.1/webservices/office/device_configuration/1')

service.submit('something')
```

Comment: Can you explain the "http://path-to-xrx-namespace" bit of your answer?

The official zeep docs write (http://my-target-namespace-here} - but what exactly is it and how do I find that from the original WSDL?

Comment: it seems, that the "path-to-xrx-namespace"  is the one returned by the "mzeep" tool from the "using zeep" section of the zeep docs. if you enter an incorrect value in here, zeep provides a helpful error message with the correct options, so if you don't understand it fully, just take the value from the error...

Comment: '{http://path-to-xrx-namespace}' is the explicit name of the namespace the binding is part of. So while 'xrx:DeviceConfigurationBinding' is the binding name, and 'xrx' is just a namespace prefix and it needs to replaced with the explicit name of the namespace e.g. '{explicit namespace name of xrx]DeviceConfigurationBinding'.